# How's rank of A is 1

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $X, Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be non zero column vectors. Find rank of $A=X\,{}Y^t$ where $Y^t$ is transpose of $Y$.

In my book it is mentioned that “every row of $A$ will be a multiple of the row vector $Y^t$. So the rank is $1$.”

Can anyone explain it to me, please?

Comment: The rows of $X^tY$ are $x_1{}^tY, \dots, x_n{}^t Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix} y_1\\y_2\\\vdots\\y_n\end{pmatrix}$ then $$A=X^tY=\begin{pmatrix} x_1y_1 &x_1y_2&\cdots& x_1y_n\\x_2y_1&x_2y_2&\cdots&x_2y_n\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\x_ny_1&x_ny_2&\cdots&x_ny_n \end{pmatrix}.$$ As you can see, the rows of this matrix are scalar multiples of the row vector $^tY$, that is, there is only one linearly independent row of $A$ (not all rows are zero because $X$ and $Y$ are nonzero columns). So rank of $A$ is one.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ and $B$ are matrices for which $AB$ makes sense, then
$$
\operatorname{rk}(AB)\le\operatorname{rk}(A)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\operatorname{rk}(AB)\le\operatorname{rk}(B)
$$
Nonzero column vectors have rank $1$, so $X\,{^t}Y$ has rank at most $1$.

Can it have rank $0$?

Comment: Nope egreg as X,Y are non zero column vectors. So, xy can't be 0 (where, x€X, y€Y). Thnx for ur valuable time. I really like ur way to approach result

Comment: @NiTiSh Yes, as in $X\,{^t}Y$ all products $x_iy_j$ appear, at least one of them will be $\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

Or: For every $v$, we have that $Av= XY'v=X\cdot\langle Y,v\rangle$ is a multiple of $X$ (and nonzero for suitable $v$, e.g., for $v=Y$), hence the range is one-dimansional.

Comment: Hagen von eitzen how XY'v=X.(Y.v) ?